# Is there a comprehensive list of date formats in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Can't find where in their docs they have all their date time formats specified?
I want a date to appear like so

```
13 Jan 2013
```

I have found this pattern:

```
date("F j, Y")
```

But this gives me the long month name. (Not sure why they have picked the rather cryptic F for a month and j for a day?)

Comment: Looks similar to PHP's date() options FYI

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
Ext.Date.format(dt, 'd M, Y')
```

Note the capital 'M' (see the full list of date formats [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Date)).

Comment: great thats exactly what I was after.